# Why Magento 2 uses both PSR-4 and PSR-0? What is the advantage of one over the other?

Tags: magento2, composer, psr

Below is the composer.json file in Magento 2, and it has used both PSR-4 and PSR-0. What is the advantages of using both in one project.

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/",
            "Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"
        },
        "psr-0": {
            "": [
                "app/code/",
                "generated/code/"
            ]
        },
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ],
        "exclude-from-classmap": [
            "**/dev/**",
            "**/update/**",
            "**/Test/**"
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Hello @Rinto George PSR-0 (the autoloading standard) and PSR-4 allows us to use composer to pull in a library and immediately use it anywhere in our code, especially when the framework leverages Dependency Injection